# MS Access Add New record and include values in specific fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to setup a button that will setup a weeks worth of tasks in a task manager I created in Access. What I'm trying to get to happen is when you click a button it creates a record and fills in the values for fields "Task Name", "Task Description", "Company", "Priority", and "Status". Each of these fields is a combo box. I was trying to use something like this:

```
  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec       
 INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status]) _
VALUES ('Change Notice', 'Daily Task', 'Ginny's', '(2) Normal', 'Not Started')
```

I get a compile error when trying this and it's probably because this is butchered from SQL code. I'm not sure what the correct syntax is to add this to Access VBA.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status]) VALUES ('Change Notice', 'Daily Task', 'Ginny''s', '(2) Normal', 'Not Started')")
```

Comment: Same syntax issues. Update: I removed the `(`' between execute and `"INSERT...` which stopped the syntax error and it will run but nothing happens.

Comment: Added the closing parenthesis. It runs now.